# Why can't I edit this XML file? Is it encrypted?

Tags: xml

I am trying to access an XML file located inside of the "resources" folder of a program I downloaded. My goal is to change the font that the program is using. I see a file called `fontstyle.xml`. When I attempt to open the file I see a huge chunk of lines that looks like the following:

```
GPPXðó´¡ ìº©¾¿¥£¢ñîýâüîóòÁÆð€‚‹ì ­¢«¯£¹¢¸ñîýîìº©¾¿¥£¢ñîýîì´¡ ö¿¼­¯©ñî¼¾©¿©¾º©îò
```

In this case I opened the file in Notepad++, but I have also tried Google Chrome and it is still unreadable. Why am I seeing this? Is the file encrypted? Am I not opening it correctly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It very unlikely its encrypted.  Its very likely its not actually a text document but simply a binary blob.

Comment: So what would that mean? Is the file able to be edited in any way?

Comment: You can ask the author of the program that question.

Comment: Just because someone stuck an ".xml" at the end of a filename, does not mean it is any such thing.

Comment: There are only three possible sources of a definitive answer to this question. The first is the application's source code or author. Assuming that the source is unavailable to you, and the author is not forthcoming, the next best sources of an answer involve reverse engineering the application to determine how the file is created, or by attempting analysis of the file itself. Both of these option are complex, potentially time consuming and may have legal ramifications.

Comment: They are both questions that we cannot answer since its unlikely somebody will spend time to reverse engineer the application in question, and its unlikely, the author of the program is a member of this community.

Comment: Upload the xml file and link to it `http://ge.tt` so people here can try it.  Try running the command `file fontstyle.xml`  within cygwin (And download the file command if you don't have it). maybe the file is in some funny format which you just need to know, and the 'file' command may reveal it.

Answer (score -1):

Could be that it was compiled using something along the lines of C.  Open it up in other programs.  Notepad++ can only read certain languages.  Even Chrome has limits.  The file your attempting to edit, what was the program written in?  Most times an entire program will be compiled under a single Language compiler.  It is rare to find .xmls ever encrypted.

Comment: This seems more like a comment than an answer.

Answer (score -1):

Open it on Notepadd++ , right click to the tab and select "clear read only flag"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnEb3.png)